# Error 500 with .htaccess after installing wordpress in XAMPP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I just exported a wordpress website to XAMPP, but when I open the page it appears a 500 server error. If i delete the content of .htaccess it returns a broken version of the home and i cannot get into wp-admin. Can this broken version depend on the content of .htaccess? Or if i delete the htaccess lines the home should work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start with just one section and see if it works. Then add more sections one by one to isolate the problem. Use this by itself for a caching performance boost:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Thank you Michael! It works but it returns that broken version. I don't know if is possible that this depends on the .htaccess file!

Comment: With any error message, particularly one as broad as the 500 Internal Server Error, you will first want to check any Apache and PHP error logs for your server. These logs can provide valuable context related to any code failures or other potential causes of a site failure. Check whether you have a file named `error_log`. If you do, report back what it says. Thanks.